# Como ocorre a atualização de campo via Ajax?

Tags: jquery

Estou com a seguinte dúvida/problema: Eu tenho um script ajax que busca o cep e preenche alguns campos na tela. Um deles é o bairro.

Na sequência eu preciso utilizar o resultado deste campo para realizar outra busca em ajax.

O que está acontecendo? Quando a chamada do segundo ajax é realizada, o campo `input` bairro ainda não está preenchido. Ou seja, a url que está sendo acionada o valor que deveria estar preenchido, não está.

Tentei criar uma variável local para armazenar esta informação para que poder utilizar na segunda chamada, e o resultado continua sendo nulo.

O que percebi quando estou na página, ao termino do script os dados são exibidos na tela, portanto somente no fim do processo é que a tela é atualizar e por isso o `input`ainda está vazio quanto tento usá-lo.

Como fazer para que o campo seja atualizado no mesmo momento de associar um valor a ele e poder utilizar no mesmo evento?

Segue abaixo meu script (apenas parte dele:

```
if(validacep.test(cep)) {

            //Preenche os campos com "..." enquanto consulta webservice.
            $("#logradouro-destino").val("...");
            $("#bairro-destino").val("...");
            $("#cidade-destino").val("...");
            $("#uf-destino").val("...");
            //$("#ibge").val("...");
            $('#info-cep').html('Logradouro');

            //Consulta o webservice viacep.com.br/
            $.getJSON("//viacep.com.br/ws/"+ cep +"/json/?callback=?", function(dados) {

                if (!("erro" in dados)) {
                    //Atualiza os campos com os valores da consulta.
                    $("#logradouro-destino").val(dados.logradouro.toUpperCase());
                    $("#bairro-destino").val(dados.bairro.toUpperCase());
                    $("#cidade-destino").val(dados.localidade.toUpperCase());
                    $("#uf-destino").val(dados.uf.toUpperCase());
                } //end if.
                else {
                    //CEP pesquisado não foi encontrado.
                    //limpa_formulário_cep();
                    $('#info-cep').html('Logradouro ***CEP não encontrado ***');
                }
            });
            // foco vai para o endereco
            $('#logradouro-destino').focus();
            var tipoItinerario = $('#tipo-itinerario').val();
            $('#valor-itinerario').val(0.00);

            if (tipoItinerario == 'K') {
                // buscar distancia
                var cepOrigem = $('#cep-origem').val();
                var cepDestino = $('#cep-destino').val();
                var url = '/calcular/' + cepOrigem + '/distancia/' + cepDestino;
                $.getJSON(url, function(dados){
                    $('#distancia-destino').val(dados);
                    buscarValor(dados);
                });
            } else if (tipoItinerario == 'A'){
                // esta chamada o campo #bairro-destino está nulo 
                var cliente = $('#cliente-id').val();
                var url = '/buscar/' + $('#bairro-destino').val() + '/valor/' + cliente + '/bairro';
                $.getJSON(url,function(dados){
                    $('#valor-destino').val(dados);
                    $('#valor-destino').maskMoney();
                });
            }
        } .
```

Comment: Sua segunda chamada getJSON está sendo chamado antes de completar o primeiro. A solução seria: async: false, mais getJSON não tem async: false como opção. Você teria que usar ajax para isso.

$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});

Comment: Ou deslocar o segundo bloco para dentro do retorno do primeiro `$.getJSON()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você está trabalhando com um método assíncrono e precisa do resultado para continuar seu fluxo, é necessário encadear a execução junto com o callback da sua primeira chamada.

E considerando que a execução só é desejada no caso de sucesso, coloquei junto ao bloco  `if (!("erro" in dados))`.

```
if (validacep.test(cep)) {

  //Preenche os campos com "..." enquanto consulta webservice.
  $("#logradouro-destino").val("...");
  $("#bairro-destino").val("...");
  $("#cidade-destino").val("...");
  $("#uf-destino").val("...");
  //$("#ibge").val("...");
  $('#info-cep').html('Logradouro');

  //Consulta o webservice viacep.com.br/
  $.getJSON("//viacep.com.br/ws/" + cep + "/json/?callback=?", function(dados) {

    if (!("erro" in dados)) {
      //Atualiza os campos com os valores da consulta.
      $("#logradouro-destino").val(dados.logradouro.toUpperCase());
      $("#bairro-destino").val(dados.bairro.toUpperCase());
      $("#cidade-destino").val(dados.localidade.toUpperCase());
      $("#uf-destino").val(dados.uf.toUpperCase());

      //Código que você quer executar apenas depois do resultado da consulta por CEP
      // foco vai para o endereco
      $('#logradouro-destino').focus();
      var tipoItinerario = $('#tipo-itinerario').val();
      $('#valor-itinerario').val(0.00);

      if (tipoItinerario == 'K') {
        // buscar distancia
        var cepOrigem = $('#cep-origem').val();
        var cepDestino = $('#cep-destino').val();
        var url = '/calcular/' + cepOrigem + '/distancia/' + cepDestino;
        $.getJSON(url, function(dados) {
          $('#distancia-destino').val(dados);
          buscarValor(dados);
        });
      } else if (tipoItinerario == 'A') {
        // esta chamada o campo #bairro-destino está nulo 
        var cliente = $('#cliente-id').val();
        var url = '/buscar/' + $('#bairro-destino').val() + '/valor/' + cliente + '/bairro';
        $.getJSON(url, function(dados) {
          $('#valor-destino').val(dados);
          $('#valor-destino').maskMoney();
        });
      }

    } //end if.
    else {
      //CEP pesquisado não foi encontrado.
      //limpa_formulário_cep();
      $('#info-cep').html('Logradouro ***CEP não encontrado ***');
    }
  });
}
```